# Backbone View element conflict with Google Maps Geocoder

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js, parse-platform, google-geocoder

This is probably not what is really happening but... from what I am seeing, calling Google Maps Geocoder erases the event listeners set on my Backbone/Parse View element. I know this sounds like I am calling several times the `render()` function without delegating events again but I am not (I triple checked!!).

Here is the event hash of the BackBone/Parse View :

```
events : {
  "click .edit_profile_cancel":    "back_to_previous_page",
  "click #form_submit":            "validate_form_and_save_pic",
  "click #change_password":        "go_to_href",
},
```

Now, when I access my View, everything works fine. If I check on the event listeners on the view element, they are all there :

[image]

This goes until I click on `#form_submit`, which on some cases calls the following code :

```
  var geocoder    = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  geocoder.geocode({
    address:                p.user.get("adress"), 
    componentRestrictions:  {
      postalCode: p.user.get("zipcode"),
      country:    MLB.stateful.user_country,
    },
  }, 


  // Geocoder callback
  function(results, status) {
    /* Bli bla bli bla bloo */
  });
```

As soon as I reach the `Bli bla bli bla bloo` part, my event listeners vanish. If I check on them the line before entering this function, the Geocoder callback, everything is as it should (Cf the image above).

But once I enter the Geocoder callback, this is what I get :

[image]

So none of my events are captured anymore, my view is just plain HTML.

Any well intended suggestion is most welcome, and much appreciated!! :)

Comment: Are you preventing the form from being submitted? Any chance of seeing a minimal functional demo on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Yes, I am preventing the form from being submitted via `event.preventDefault()`. 

I'll check how I can move all this to Fiddle. This doesn't sound quick but I am stuck so...

Comment: I don't know why it does this, but as we say in french : "Night is a great advisor". After reading my question again, I thought that an easy workaround would be to delegate events again after the Geocoder callback erased them. So I did exactly that, I called `this.delegateEvents()` after the Geocoder callback, which temporarily solves the issue. 

This is a workaround, not a fix, but that will do for today. I'll come back with an access to our app, so you guys can have a demo of the issue if willing to investigate this strange behaviour with me.

Tanks @muistooshort for your comment

Comment: Sounds like something somewhere is doing an `$(whatever).html(...)` on something that is part of a Backbone view. The `.html` call will nuke events but can leave the HTML apparently intact. At least that's what's usually behind "disappearing events that are fixed by manually calling `delegateEvents`". The usual fixes are not re-using views (destroy and create them as needed instead) or binding views to existing DOM nodes (let the view create and own its `el` instead).

Comment: I feel quite ashamed, but I finally found it. A team member was actually calling `undelegateEvents()` somewhere down the callback road, and I just hadn't seen it... 

Many thanks for your help and guidance. That did helped me to reflect on the issue and made me ask the right questions

Comment: No worries, someone calling `undelegateEvents` is a pretty strange thing to be doing (and sounds like someone kludging around a bug), that's not an obvious thing to look for.